# How to deal with python imports so they work easily with py2 and py3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am looking for a way to write python packages and modules that makes them Python 3 friendly and also it makes easy to import them.

Most common case is that you have one major class that you want to provide to the users, call it `MyCode`.

Your package would be named `mycode` and you would put the body of MyCode class into `mycode/mycode.py`.

Now, you would expect that people could do one of these:

```
import mycode
obj = mycode.MyClass()
```

or:

```
from mycode import MyClass()
obj = MyClass()
```

Now, the question is what you should put inside the `__init__.py` in order to make this work, in both python 2.6+ and 3.x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use absolute imports, it'll work fine across python versions. Inside `mycode/__init__.py` put:

```
from __future__ import absolute_import

from mycode.mycode import MyClass
```

where the `__future__` import works from Python 2.5 and onwards; see [PEP 328](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0328/). Without the `absolute_import` import, `import mycode` is ambiguous; Python 3 will treat it as absolute and load the top-level package, Python 2 treats it as relative and import the nested module instead.

The alternative is to use a relative import:

```
from .mycode import MyClass
```

which will work across the same spectrum of versions.

Answer (score 0):

Adding `from mycode import *` to the start of `mycode/__init__.py` is going to make the content of `mycode/mycode.py` importable from the `mycode` package like it was just a normal module like `mycode.py`, same as when you `import mycode` from the same directory as your `mycode.py` script (`/mycode/`) or do a relative import to `mycode/mycode.py` ...